# How to access the screen size in html?

Tags: html, screen

Is it possible?

Comment: please expand. Why do you want to do that? If you want, say, to have a `div` that is half of the screen width you can use `50%`, as its width.

Comment: @nico so I can use all components width and height with percentages? sounds cool.. for fonts size too (so they fit)?

Comment: @Tom Brito: sure, but I would suggest to implement that in CSS rather then straight in the HTML (although that is valid too), as it makes things much cleaner. Font size is more tricky: you can use px (pixel) although that's discouraged, `em` is a better choice, see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_units.asp

Comment: See also:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/ and http://www.alistapart.com/articles/elastic/

Comment: If you use ems for font size be sure to set the font-size for the body to be 62.5%. That will make it much easier to figure out the font sizes you want to use since 1em = 10px if you scale fonts down that way.

Comment: @Brent Friar: you cannot make a general equivalence between `em` and `px`, as that is dependent from browser/system user preferences.

Comment: You are correct, the 1em = 10px only at the default medium font size. TO be completely accurate I should have added that using ems throughout your CSS will allow your entire site to scale proportionally with 1em = 10px a the default browser setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with javascript using `window.screen`. [See here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

no. but you can create layouts that depends not on pixels or cm, but percentages. they are called liquid layouts. also you can define a minimun width or height to be sure your layout won't broke in minnor screens.

other alternatives includes client side scripting (like javascript) as already said by the others.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're asking to center something onto the screen/browser window:

Use CSS:

```
.cen {
  margin: auto;
}
```

and in case it is a picture you want to center:

```
.cen {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -<witdh of image>/2;
  margin-top: -<height of image>/2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another great way to do this is using `@media` queries.

A brief overview can be found here; http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/

Or a more thorough explanation from the W3C; http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

This may not be the best option if you're worried about a lack of support on older browsers, but if you're not, this is the best way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Not in HTML, but in JavaScript.

`window.screen` has `width` and `height` properties.